# Does C free memory itself after allocating it outside local function?

Tags: c, http, malloc, free

This is code fragment of basic http server

```
void sendFile(int socketNumber,char *filePath) {
    char *wwwFolder = "htdocs";
    int newFilePathSize = strlen("htdocs") + strlen(filePath) + 1;
    char *filePathFull = (char*) malloc(newFilePathSize); // allocating memory
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(wwwFolder); i++)
        filePathFull[i] = wwwFolder[i];
    int j = 0;
    for ( ;i < newFilePathSize; i++)
    {
        filePathFull[i] = filePath[j++];
    }
    filePathFull[i] = '\0';

    //free(filePath); --
    /*filePath is a pointer with already allocated
    memory from previous function, however, if I try to free it
    in this function the program breaks down with this error:
    *** glibc detected *** ./HTTP: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x09526008 *** */

    FILE *theFile = fopen(filePathFull,"r");
    printf("|"); printf(filePathFull); printf("| - FILEPATH\n");
    if (theFile == NULL)
    {
        send404(socketNumber);
        return;
    }
    else
        sendLegitFile(socketNumber,theFile,filePathFull);


    free(filePathFull); // freeing memory allocated in this
        //function seems to be okay
}
```

I want to ask, does C handle memory that was allocated itself? Is it freed while program is till running? Or is it my fault that I can't free filePath memory which was declared in previous function?

Comment: It is easyer to allocate trivial buffers like these in automatic storage ("on the stack") Also, you could use memcpy() or strcpy() or snprintf() to construct the path.

Answer (score 2):

There is no garbage collection in c.
If you allocated memory using `malloc` you should deallocate using `free`.

If you don't do so the memory leaks untill your program ends. After which OS reclaims the memory.

Answer (score 2):

In C, you can only release memory with `free` that was explicitly obtained with `malloc` (or `calloc` or `realloc`). And `free` is finicky in that it needt to receive the exact same pointer value that was returned by `malloc`.

If memory was obtained in some other way (for example with an array on the stack, or a string-literal, or ...), it is a bug to pass a pointer to that memory to `free`.

---

To avoid problems, it is generally recommended to keep allocation and release of memory in the same function or in a pair of related functions, so you can easily verify that the memory passed to `free` was obtained from `malloc` (or its kin)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Als said, the massively accepted convention in C for memory management is that the “person” that did the `malloc` is the one in charge of the `free`. As you did not allocate `filePath` you should not `free` it: the responsible person will do it. If you also do, it will result in a double free (and probably other woes if the caller tries to use `filePath` after you return).